# ASP.net CSS error on button hover

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have this button 
`<button type="submit" id="wow">
                   <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Log In
                </button>`

I am trying to enter a Font Awesome Icon at the login button.
the CSS code is this:

```
#wow{
    padding-top:10px;
    background-color:red;
    border:none;
    float: left;

    color:#333333;
    width: 120px;
    height:120px;
}
```

and for :hover just this

```
  #wow :hover {
        background-color: green;

    }
```

This is the button in normal state.
[image: image1]

this is the button hover. 
[image: image2]

it changes the background only of the icon...

any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: remove space between  #wow:hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the space between `#wow` and `:hover`. Currently your hover will be applied to the buttons descendants

```css
#wow {
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  float: left;
  color: #333333;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
#wow:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="submit" id="wow">
  <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Log In
</button>
```